# Shiny: Replace renderPlotly errors with some text description or default plot

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a Shiny App and I want to use the `brush` function. The app currently looks like:

[image]

Where in the one `box()` I get the error `Error: argument 1 is not a vector`. This error disappears when the user makes a brushed selection of the plot.

[image]

How can I mask the error into a more user friendly description such as "Please select an area of the above plot in order to generate this window...".

The plot `box()` is supposed to plot the user selection such as a zoom-in version of the plot.

Code:

```
data <- mtcars



library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(text = "Main Menu", tabName = "MainPage")
    )
)
body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "MainPage",
                fluidRow(
                    box(
                        width = 12,
                        plotOutput("myPlot1", brush = "userSelectedSummaryStatistics")
                    )
                ),
                fluidRow(
                    box(
                        width = 4,
                        DT::dataTableOutput("userDefinedTable")
                    ),
                    box(
                        width = 8,
                        plotlyOutput("selectedUserDataFromUserDefinedTable")
                    )
                )
        )
    )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(
    header, sidebar, body
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    output$myPlot1 <- renderPlot({
        data %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
            geom_line()
    })
    
    selectedUserData = reactive({
        userSelectedSummaryStatistics = input$userSelectedSummaryStatistics
        userSelection = brushedPoints(data, userSelectedSummaryStatistics)
        return(userSelection)
    })
    
    output$userDefinedTable = DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(selectedUserData()))
    
    output$selectedUserDataFromUserDefinedTable <- renderPlotly({
        ggplotly(
            selectedUserData() %>% 
                ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
                geom_line()
        )
    })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`validate`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/validate.html):

```
  output$selectedUserDataFromUserDefinedTable <- renderPlotly({
    validate(need(nrow(selectedUserData())>0,'Please select an area of the above plot in order to generate this window'))
    ggplotly(
      selectedUserData() %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
        geom_line()
    )
  })
```

[image]